# Declare resource included by maven-bundle-plugin as optional

Tags: java, maven, osgi, osgi-bundle, maven-bundle-plugin

I have a multi-module build creating multiple artifacts with package type "bundle".

Some of them create some information in the META-INF directory during compile time, some don't.

I tried to define an instruction in the parent pom.xml that adds the META-INF directory as a resource to the bundle.
Unfortunately this fails for those artifacts not creating the META-INF directory during the build time.

I tried to avoid defining this rule on all modules that currently DO creating the META-INF directory since

- There is a lot and
- maybe the others will create the META-INF directory in the future and this will require future developers to know that they have to add this directory as a resource now.

Is it somehow possible to make this "include-resource" instruction optional, meaning it ignores this resource if it's missing?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <instructions>
            <Include-Resource>META-INF=${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF</Include-Resource>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefixing the resource pattern with `-` should suffice, e.g.:

```xml
<Include-Resource>-META-INF=${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF</Include-Resource>
```

Documentation [here](https://bnd.bndtools.org/instructions/includeresource.html#ignoring-missing-sources).

Comment: Great, thank you! I just looked at the documentation of the maven-bundle-plugin :(